# How to get Eclipse code template store through plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

This is how i implemented, but the added template not reflecting in the code templates preferences page

```
        private static final String TEMPLATE_STORE_KEY = "java-statements";

        IPreferenceStore prefs = myPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore();

        templateStore = new ContributionTemplateStore(null, prefs, TEMPLATE_STORE_KEY);


        try {
            templateStore.load();
        } catch (final IOException ioex) {
            //
        }
        templateStore.startListeningForPreferenceChanges();
    }
      Template newTemplate = new Template("testSysout", "testSysout", "java",
            "System.out.println(${word_selection}${});${cursor}",false);

     TemplatePersistenceData myTemplate = new TemplatePersistenceData(newTemplate, true , "testSysout");
    templateStore.add(myTemplate);

    templateStore.save();
```

Comment: As far as I can make out that page only shows code templates defined by the JDT plug-in.

Comment: @greg-449 : when i tried through xml template import it shows up perfectly. not able to do via plugin code